# Catching and Analyzing Internet packets

Tags: java, security, network-programming, ethernet, modem

There is a common internal line in the office place, this line cannot be used for the Internet but somehow someone using this line to connect to the Internet. This threatens the company's safety in terms of data thieves. 
Programmatically, how to analyze the internal line and find whose computer is connected to the Internet.

```
                    OFFICE
   |____________________________________________|
   |                                            |
   |     -------------------------------        |
   |            internal phone line             |
   |     -------------------------------        |
   |     ||                                     |
   |     ? IP                                   | 
   |                                            |
   |____________________________________________|
```

Marked with ?, it uses Internet over prohibited office internal line. However, I donot know whose computer is open to the Internet ( whether user uses Internet un-intentionally). One by one testing in not possible because there are many computers in the office place. How to detect IP address of the this computer, programmatically ? While connecting to the Internet, packet should use this line, is it possible to catch and analyze this Internet packet, programmatically ?

Comment: I think this time it is more clear. Am I right ?

Comment: Not sure I understand your internal/external network connectivity, but could you use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to collect/analyze all packets on your network and then look for external IP addresses.  You will see these being sent to some internal IP address (or scanning for them if some penetration testing is being done).

Comment: @rickhg12hs thanks for your highlight. To clarify, internal network is for connecting all of the electronic devices in the office, and at some point, this internal network is connected to the external line -- phone line --. Someone using this internal to reach external in order to use Internet for good or bad. Is it okey ?

Comment: Knowing the technologies involved would be helpful.  Is your internal network ethernet?  Is your external line DSL or some other modem connected to phone line?  Is your ethernet connected to a DSL modem? Is someone using their private dial-up modem Internet service provider direct to their computer over the office phone line?  Do you have access to office phone records?

Comment: @rickhg12hs Your case supports is incrediable. Internal network = Ethernet, possibly someone using modem which is directly connected with internal line, via internal line s/he reaches to the external, and I donot have access to office phone records.

Comment: A determined insider or a compromised machine could connect via the separate external line and leave no direct trace of this on the internal network.  You could install/enable monitoring/logging software on each machine that could be used to determine network interface usage, etc.  Although, a compromised machine could do well by covering its tracks.  Do you have current evidence of internal/external network "leakage"?  What is it?

Comment: Would be even better if you changed your security to make it impossible to use the wrong connection for external access, not just rely on courtesy for doing so!

Comment: @ToBe:  And the only way to insure that is to rip out hardware.

Comment: I dont know your exact case, but a firewall / router configuration might also do the trick. But we would need a whole lot of more information to find a good answer for it. My comment was just a reminder that any security that can be bypassed will be bypassed, no matter what you do.